# display top left corner of div relative to mouse click event

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript (jQuery not available here)
How do I display the top left corner of my div relative to my mouse click location? The following seems to work until I have to scroll my page and then it becomes inaccurate.

```
    function MyJsFx() {
        var div1 = document.getElementById('noteContent');
        div1.style.display = "block";
        div1.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
        div1.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.scrollY` and `window.scrollX` as scrolling offsets. You can then subtract the the window scroll position from the values you already have to get a relative position value.

Comment: The following worked for me. Any insight as to why?
var x_offset = self.pageXOffset;
var y_offset = self.pageYOffset;

Read more: http://www.ehow.com/how_12119128_obtain-scroll-offsets-javascript.html#ixzz2bRWz3tpS

Answer (score 0):

Somethime using javascript is not cross-browser.

You need detected browser before use method **event.clientY** or **window.scrollY**